# Windows Phone 8.1 Display Part of Webpage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am making an app which wraps a webpage. However, I only want to display part of the page (the rest has a bunch of junk.) I need to get the element I want to show by the id and display it in a `WebView`. But `HtmlDocument` and the likes doesn't seem to work in WP 8.1. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use htmlAgilityPack instead? It's a little overkill, but will do the job. You can get the package off nuget. `(Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack)`

Use is pretty well documented if you do a search, but you want to load the doc into it, extract the node you want, then feed that to the WebView control.

You mention HtmlDocument, so I'm assuming you're just wanting to display specific static pages from a site? This won't work if you want navigation or anything more than that.

Comment: Any idea on giving that node to the WebView? Bing is coming up blank on that one.

Comment: You can use WebView.NavigateToString() https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigatetostring.aspx

Comment: Does that remove the styling?

Comment: .....actually yes. You'll need to re-wrap it in a <body> and append the <head> from the original doc, along with with the stylesheets if they're hosted locally - In which case I'd probably just programatically download them and insert them inline to the 'page'. There's probably a better solution now considering this...

Comment: Well if there's a better solution I'd be happy to hear it, but will keep this as answer until / unless one is posted.